# React Semantic-ui-react Mobx search component

Tags: reactjs, mobx, semantic-ui-react

I am new to all three of these frameworks and am hoping to get some assistance. I am attempting to filter a table based on the values of my mobx Map.

Dashboard component:

```
const ServerCatalogDashboard: React.FC = () => {
    const serverCatalogStore = useContext(ServerCatalogStore)
    const {searchServerCatalog,searchResults,searchValue} = serverCatalogStore
    useEffect(() => {
        serverCatalogStore.loadServerCatalog();
    }, [serverCatalogStore]);

    if(serverCatalogStore.loadingStatus) return <LoadingComponent content='Loading servers from database' />

    return (
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Column width={12}>
                <ServerCatalogTable />
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column width={4}>
                <h2>Catalog Filters</h2>
                <Search
                    results={searchResults}
                    value={searchValue}
                    onSearchChange={searchServerCatalog}
                />
            </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
    )
}

export default observer(ServerCatalogDashboard)
```

MobX Store:

```
configure({enforceActions: 'always'});

class ServerCatalogStore {
    @observable serverCatalogRegistry = new Map()
    @observable loadingStatus = false;
    @observable searchResults = [];
    @observable searchValue = '';

    @computed get serversByProvider() {
        //Need to find  way to filter them by provider
        return Array.from(this.serverCatalogRegistry.values());
    }

    //Do filtering by provider here
    groupServersByProvider(servers: IAWSInstance[]) {
        return servers;
    }

    @action loadServerCatalog = async ()=>{
        this.loadingStatus = true;
        try {
            const servers = await agent.Servers.list();
            runInAction('loading servers',() => {
                servers.forEach(server => {
                    this.serverCatalogRegistry.set(server.id,server);
                });
                this.loadingStatus = false;
                console.log(toJS(this.serverCatalogRegistry));
            });
        } catch (error) {
            runInAction('error loading servers', () => {
                this.loadingStatus = false;
            })
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    @action searchServerCatalog(e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>) {
        this.searchValue = e.target.value;
        this.searchResults = _.filter(this.serverCatalogRegistry.values, this.searchValue);
    }
}

export default createContext(new ServerCatalogStore());
```

Right now I am not even interesting in updating the table, but just want to get the drop down showing the proper filtered results. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Always appreciated.

Error: I think this is most likely a red herring, and the issue lies within how I'm attempting to solve this.

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & HTMLElement'.  TS2339

    58 |     //   }
    59 |     @action searchServerCatalog(e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>) {
  > 60 |         this.searchValue = e.currentTarget.value;
       |                                            ^
    61 |         this.searchResults = _.filter(this.serverCatalogRegistry.values, this.searchValue);
    62 |     }
    63 | }
```

EDIT: Now I'm getting back the right amount "results" in my Search component, however they are just blank... This is the action I am running in MobX.

```
@action searchServerCatalog = async (e:any) => {
    try {
        runInAction('loading search matches', ()=>{
            this.searchValue = e.currentTarget.value;
            let matchesFilter = new RegExp(this.searchValue, "i");
            this.searchResults = Array.from(this.serverCatalogRegistry.values()).filter(server => matchesFilter.test(server.name));
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: What results are you currently getting? Could you add that to the question please?